# Rails 5 show image using image_tag from personal folder not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a custom folder which is accessed by other application this is the path folder in my server:

```
/home/john/logos/
```

this folder contains: one.png, two.png, three.png, so on..

in my view:

```
<%= image_tag  "/home/john/logo/one.png"%>
```

but the image is not show, and the output console show this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home/john/logo/one.png")
```

I don t want to copy to app/public/ because it is used by other applications and the images are changed frequently, the image must be shown from this path.
What I am missing?

Comment: `/home/john/logos/`
 is it in your assets/images  ?

Comment: If the `/home/john/logos/` does not reside inside rails app directory, then it does not use asset pipeline. What you could is define an action in a controller and a route to render the image.

Comment: if on production there is no file in (I guess) `public/assets/home/john/logos`

Answer (score 0):

Vishal already gave a hint the image_tag helper is looking for files in your assets path. I think you can add the path to Rails.application.config.assets.paths in your configuration. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html.

`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "/home/john/logo/one.png"`

Or you can choose the option Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna gave.